# shell command in python script with arguments not working

Tags: python, shell

I'm using a command shell on my script python to retrieve the Id of the last scenario created. (only 1 scenario)
I want to retrieve many scenarios by specifying an argument on my python in order to retrieve like 3 or 4 last scenario's ID.

This is my code:

```
import argparse 
import os 
import subprocess 
import one_sdk 
import time 
import argparse 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('num', help='Number of scenarios to select', default=1, type=int) 
options = parser.parse_args() 

process = "path/one-ctl so list kind:one.scenario.SharedScenario | tail -'{num}' | awk '{print $1}'" 

retrieveId = subprocess.check_output(process, shell=True).rstrip() 

print(retrieveId)
```

When I execute the script num is not known.
can anyone help me thanks to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
process = "path/one-ctl so list kind:one.scenario.SharedScenario | tail -'%i' | awk '{print $1}'" % options.num
```